# My Map Function Does Not Return Any Information?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a simple expenses react app. In this app, users enter a description, amount, and date for a particular expense item. This expense item or the "Budget" state is saved in the back-end. Now, whenever the user loads the page then a GET request is made to retrieve "Budget" and is outputted to a table.

The issue is the API returns information, but the map function doesn't output anything to the table.

Here is how the data looks in mongoDB:

```
_id:[some id] 
desc:"Lodging"
amount:30
date:"2020-05-02T03:28:49.000Z"

_id:[some id]
desc:"Shopping"
amount:120
date:"2020-05-02T03:55:41.000Z"
```

Here is what the API returns when I console log it:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "budget": [
    {
      "_id": "someId",
      "desc": "Lodging",
      "amount": 30,
      "date": "2020-05-02T03:28:49.000Z",
      "createdAt": "2020-05-18T03:29:01.879Z",
      "updatedAt": "2020-05-18T03:29:01.879Z",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "someId",
      "desc": "Shopping",
      "amount": 120,
      "date": "2020-05-02T03:55:41.000Z",
      "createdAt": "2020-05-22T03:56:08.670Z",
      "updatedAt": "2020-05-22T03:56:08.670Z",
      "__v": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is the full code:

```
 const [Budget, setBudget] = useState([]);

  const [loadingBudget, setloadingBudget] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("[API Route]")
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.data.success) {
          console.log(response.data);
          setBudget([...Budget, response.data.budget]);
        } else {
          alert("Failed to get Budget");
        }
      });
    setloadingBudget(false);
  }, []);

 const values = Budget.map((i) => {
    return (
      <tr>
        <td>{i.desc}</td>
        <td>{i.amount}</td>
      </tr>
    );
  });

return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <table
        style={{ width: "40%", marginTop: "-300px", marginLeft: "720px" }}
        className="highlight">
        <thead className="thead-light">
          <tr>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>{!loadingBudget && values}</tbody>
      </table>
    </React.Fragment>
```

I figured that the component might render before the API returns a result. As a result, I added the loadingBudget state to help fix that. However, the map function (i.e. values) doesn't return anything. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your API response looks like an array of arrays, the outer array having two elements, and the first element being an array of two elements. It would be helpful if you could use `console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data, null, 2))` so that we could see the actual structure sent back...

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks for the suggestion. I updated what the response looks like.

Answer (score 0):

When you get the data from the API, make sure you spread it into the array. So, the following line:

```
setBudget([...Budget, response.data.budget]);
```

becomes

```
setBudget([...Budget, ...response.data.budget]);
```

Then, move the `Budget.map(...)` code into the `<tbody>{!loadingBudget && values}</tbody>` area instead of assigning it to `values` so that it ends up as:

```
<tbody>{!loadingBudget && Budget.map((i) => (
  <tr>
    <td>{i.desc}</td>
    <td>{i.amount}</td>
  </tr>
))}</tbody>
```

I think what's happening is that `values` is getting the value of the `map` when `Budget` is initially an empty array ... which is to say, nothing.

If you put `Budget` into the brackets, React will see that it's an Observable and, well, observe it :). Then, when it changes to have data, it will render appropriately.

Comment: I actually figured it out. As you mentioned before it's a nested array. So, I had to do a second map function. This worked: `{!loadingBudget &&
            Budget.map(function (subarray) {
              return subarray.map(function (val) {
                return (
                  <tr>
                    <td>{val.desc}</td>
                    <td>{val.amount}</td>
                  </tr>
                );
              });
            })}`

I'm curious why did Budget become become a nested array?

Comment: you should try to console.log your `Budget` useState on render (before return), if it console the correct array (not nested). As long your `Budget` has the correct data structure `[{...},{...},{...}]`, this answer should work tho

Comment: Oh, I see why! `[...Budget, response.data.budget]` should be `[...Budget, ...response.data.budget]`. You need to spread the response data too.

Comment: So, if we didn't add the spread operator to response.data.budget then every GET request would add another nested array to "Budget" is that correct?